# Atomic projection in $W^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

let $A$ be $C*$-algebra. $A^{**}$ is enveloping $W^*$-algebra of $A$. I want to know that what is meaning of  atomic projection  in $A^{**}$ and why the l.u.b of all atomic projection of $A^{**}$ is a central projection.

Any references can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

A projection $p$ is atomic when for any other projection $q\leq p$ we have either $q=0$ or $q=p$, i.e. there are no non-trivial atomic projections below $p$.

Following Lemma 3.42 from *Geometry of state space of Operator Algebras* by Alfsen and Schultz:

Let $z=\vee \{p \text{ atomic}\}$. Any unital order isomorphism $\Phi$ sends atomic projections to atomic projections and is normal, so that $\Phi(z)=z$. In particular for any projection $q$ we can consider the conjugation map with $1-2q$ which is a unital order isomorphism. Since $(1-2q)z(1-2q)=z$ it follows that $qz=zq$ which means that $z$ is central.